# Having trouble developing protein sequence segmentation

Tags: arrays, vb.net, visual-studio

I am having trouble screating a program to split up a protein

```
Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Dim apomyoglobin As String
        apomyoglobin = "'GLSDGEWQQVLNVWGKVEADIAGHGQEVLIRLFTGHPETLEKFDKFKHLKTEAEMKASEDLKKHGTVVLTALGGILKKKEGH
HEAELKPLAQSHATKHKIPIKYLEFISDAIIHVLHSKHRPGDFGADAQGAMTKALELFRNDIAAKYKELGFQG'"
        Dim thearray() As String = apomyoglobin.Split("") 'Stores the array of the string'
        For i = 0 To (Len(apomyoglobin) - 1)
            If thearray(i) Then
        Next

    End Sub

End Module
```

I want to split the sequence at specific letters i.e

Cutting the string after an arginine(R)

Cutting after a lysine(K)

Does not cut if lysine or argine is followed by proline(P)

I am stuck on exactly how to split this array into seperate chunks without removing any characters.I Just want to put certain ones into an array

Comment: `Split` removes characters so, if you don't want to remove characters, why are you using `Split`? Use `indexOf` (or `IndexOfAny`) and `Substring` in a loop. As you should ALWAYS do, work out the logic first and only write code when that's done. The code should then explicitly implement the logic you already have. If you don't know what code to write, you should be able to tell us EXACTLY what step of your algorithm you are trying to implement.

Comment: The string 'apomyoglobin' you provided does not contain 'arginine','lysine' or 'proline', please provide a detailed description about your question.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of splitting using `IndexOfAny` and `Substring` in a loop, wrapped into an extension method:

```vb
Imports System.Runtime.CompilerServices

Public Module StringExtensions

    <Extension>
    Public Function SplitAtChars(source As String, ParamArray chars As Char()) As String()
        Dim substrings As New List(Of String)

        'Start at the beginning of the source text.
        Dim startIndex = 0

        'Find the first delimiter.
        Dim endIndex As Integer = source.IndexOfAny(chars)

        Do Until endIndex = -1
            'Get the substring from the current start index to and including the current delimiter.
            substrings.Add(source.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex + 1))

            'Start again after the current delimiter.
            startIndex = endIndex + 1

            'Find the next delimiter.
            endIndex = source.IndexOfAny(chars, startIndex)
        Loop

        'Get the substring from after the last delimiter to the end of the source text.
        substrings.Add(source.Substring(startIndex))

        Return substrings.ToArray()
    End Function

End Module
```

Example usage:

```vb
Dim text = "AB1CD2DEF1GHIJK1LMN2OPQR2STU1VW2XYZ"
Dim text1 = "1AB1CD2DEF1GHIJK1LMN2OPQR2STU1VW2XYZ"
Dim text2 = "AB1CD2DEF1GHIJK1LMN2OPQR2STU1VW2XYZ2"

Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", text.SplitAtChars("1"c, "2"c)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", text1.SplitAtChars("1"c, "2"c)))
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",", text2.SplitAtChars("1"c, "2"c)))
```

Output:

```
AB1,CD2,DEF1,GHIJK1,LMN2,OPQR2,STU1,VW2,XYZ
1,AB1,CD2,DEF1,GHIJK1,LMN2,OPQR2,STU1,VW2,XYZ
AB1,CD2,DEF1,GHIJK1,LMN2,OPQR2,STU1,VW2,XYZ2,
```

You can adjust as required for your specific case.

Comment: Sorry But this is kind of  confusing to me. Is it possible that you could explain in laymans terms

Comment: How about you do what you can first, which should be the case every time without prompting? Create a new project, add the code I provided above, set a breakpoint at the top of the code, run the project and then step through it line by line to see what it actually does. You can see the value of every variable at every step and you can use the F1 key to open the documentation for any type or method in the code to read for yourself what it does. You can make an effort on your own behalf and then ask specific questions on specific points that you don't understand if you need to.